# how to create a struck which could be unpacked to N variables in Python2?

Tags: python

I want to define N variables with different int values (as state mark, so only requirement is that each var's value is different).
At first I have:

```py
state_default, state_open, state_close = range(3)
```

then some time passed, to add new state var I'll change it to code below

```py
state_default, state_open, state_close, state_error = range(4)
```

and somehow I often forget to alter range(3) to range(4), so Exception about unpacking will be raised.

I know in python3, it could be handled like this:

```py
state_default, state_open, state_close, *placeholder = range(1000)
```

So I wonder if there is a solution in python2 **where** I can unpack a object for infinite times(or just many many times)

In a word I want it could pass test below

```py
a,b,c = InfiniteUnpackableObject()  # shouldn't give me unpacking error
a,b,c,d = InfiniteUnpackableObject()  # shouldn't give me unpacking error either
```

Comment: Python cannot know how many output variables you have, so this will never work. This doesn't work in Python 3 either---you have to use * on one of the args (which converts the rest into a *list* so it can't be infinite).

Comment: Will it always be either 3 or 4 args or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> it = iter(range(4))
>>> a = next(it)
>>> b = next(it)
>>> c = next(it)
>>> d = list(it)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>> d
[3]
```

More generally, as a generator:

```
def unpack_collect(iterable, n):
    """Yields the first n values of an interable, and returns the rest as a list."""
    it = iter(iterable)
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(it)
    yield list(it)
```

And in use:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = unpack_collect('qwerty', 3))
>>> (a, b, c, d)
('q', 'w', 'e', ['r', 't', 'y'])
```

Comment: Please put the test code into your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I just don't want to pass n to it.

Comment: No worries, pretty sure that's going to be impossible though. Even in Python 3, you have to put a * on *one* of the output vars, which is equivalent to typing in a number like `n`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation. I see now, I just expected too much